# React return state

Tags: reactjs, web, react-state

```
import React from "react";
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'


export default class Tokens extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    number: null
  };


  async outDataTockens(val){
    val.forEach((ele,ind) =>{
      console.log(ele);
    })
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    let tokensvar = '<tr> <td>1</td> <td>2</td> </tr>';
    const url = "https://api.multiversx.com/accounts/erd1n0kgesdn7hc63amdfygqfdj9enfa07n2hwup9y8732fg35qcug8q0w0x8s/tokens";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    data.forEach((ele,ind) =>{
      tokensvar += '<tr> <td>{ele.name}</td> <td>{ele.name}</td> </tr>';
                  
      //<tr> <td>{ele.name}</td> <td>{ele.name}</td> </tr>
      //tokensvar + " " + ele.name;
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(tokensvar));
      this.setState({ number: tokensvar, loading: false });
      //console.log(this.state.number);
    })
    //console.log(this.state);
  }

  

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <div>loading...</div>;
    }

    if (!this.state.number) {
      return <div>didn't get number</div>;
    }
    


    return (
      <div>
        <table className="Token-section-output"> {this.state.number} </table>
      </div>
      
    );
  }
}
```

why {this.state.number} return : "xxxx"
And how to do for this return : xxxx

???

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQRJC.png)

I dont know what i must do
I tried a lot of things but I don't know what to do I'm lost, but I still think it's a simple error and easy to solve aresolved for an experimenter, in any case thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does calling react setState method not mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-does-calling-react-setstate-method-not-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: Tip: **do not ever create HTML strings in React**. Instead use proper **JSX elements** in the `render()` function. I propose that you search the internet for **`jsx create table`**, you'll find lots of great tutorials which will give better results than what you are doing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls update the data into component's state as an array and then render using map fun.

[here is an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-feistel-lxqe0f?file=/src/App.js)

- update API response

```
 const data = await response.json();
 this.setState({ rows: data });
```

- render table's row

```
 render(){
   <table className="Token-section-output">
    <p>table row</p>
    {rows.map((row) => (
      <tr>
        <td>{row?.name}</td>
      </tr>
     ))}
   </table>
 }
```

if it is possible, we should use reactHook to manage the state of components and there are many benefits. smaller components and easy to control the state and so on.

Comment: in your example it does not return as an html element but as a string https://ibb.co/t3qjhr3

Comment: I think you should do. update the data into state and use that data to map inside of render function ```const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();
      this.setState({ rows: data });``` and then render(){ rows.map((row)=><tr><td>{}{row?.name}</td></tr>)}

Comment: I've updated my example code. that is looks more convenience. pls check it here https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-feistel-lxqe0f